# SQL Procedure calculate a column by given percentage

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a table with columns: ProductCode, productLine, Saleprice. I need to write procedure to calculate new sale price based on a given number for a specific product Line, then update on this table as well.

```
@newprice = (SELECT Saleprice FROM temp_table WHERE productLine = @line)* @percentage;

update temp_table
Saleprice = @newprice WHERE productLine = @line
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what's your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UPDATE` query and update the `Saleprice` directly

```
UPDATE t
SET    Saleprice = t.Saleprice  * @percentage
FROM   temp_table t
WHERE  t.productLine = @line
```

---

If you need to create a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE markup_salesprice
    @line int,
    @percentage decimal(10,2)
AS
BEGIN

  UPDATE t
  SET    Saleprice = t.Saleprice  * @percentage
  FROM   temp_table t
  WHERE  t.productLine = @line

END
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But in case, the percentage is a random number for different changes. I have to make a procedure which only input the rate and line for this time then return output new price for this.

Comment: Don't quite understand your last comment. What is the issue ?